# Django update_or_create()

Tags: python, django, sql-update, filter

I'm following Django documentation regarding update_or_create() but could not pass the primary key (obj_key) to defaults. Basically I need to check if exist user_id and wallet_id and update with the new value. If not create new record.

```
class ModelSelectedWallet(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wallet = models.name = models.ForeignKey(ModelWallet, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(verbose_name='Created', auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateField(verbose_name='Modified', auto_now=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='selected_wallet_created_by', blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='selected_wallet_modified_by', blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)


def select_wallet(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        wallet_id = request.POST['wallet_id']
        user = get_current_user()
        user_id = user.id
        db = ModelSelectedWallet
        
        obj_key = db.objects.filter(user_id__exact=user_id, wallet_id__exact=wallet_id).values('id')[0]['id']
        defaults = {'id': obj_key}
        
        try:
            obj = db.objects.get(user_id=user_id, wallet_id=wallet_id)
            for key, value in defaults.items():
                setattr(obj, key, value)
            obj.save()
        except db.DoesNotExist:
            new_values = {
                        'created': datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y-%m-%d"),
                        'created_by_id': user_id,
                        'modified_by_id': user_id,
                        'wallet_id': wallet_id,
                        'user_id': user_id
            }
            new_values.update(defaults)
            obj = db(**new_values)
            obj.save()
```

Comment: Poderia traduzir a pergunta? ou refazer esta mesma no stackoverflow em inglês.

Comment: Poderia postar o form? Gostaria de ver o modelform ou form correspondente ao seu formulário html.